# How to "Org LaTeX Exporting (to PDF)" only current subheading from elisp function?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

In `org-export-dispatch` `(C-c C-e)`, there is an option for `Export-scope` from (`Buffer` vs `Subtree`) which is bind for (`C-s`). I frequently use this `Subtree` when exporting to LaTeX PDF.

**Problem**:
So I frequently do: `C-c` `C-e` `C-s` `l` `p`. This feels too much key-strokes.

**Question**:
How to export with `Subtree` option using elisp function, so that I can bind it to fewer key-stokes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops sorry, it was too trivial:

```
(org-latex-export-to-pdf nil t)
```

When the 2-nd argument is `non-nil` as like above, it exports only `subtree`.

/However, not sure why it fails to produce PDF (at least in my case) when 1-st argument is `t`/

Comment: "... not sure why it fails to produce PDF (at least in my case) when 1-st argument is t" : that argument is the `async` argument which is what is set with `C-c C-e C-a ...` in the interactive dispatcher. To debug, set `org-export-async-debug` to `t` first, try the export and then visit the buffer `*Org Export Process*` to see what went wrong.